# Bring activity to front with intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Hy,

I'm making a simple stop-watch. When I click on the Start button, a notification shows up in the Status Bar. When I click on the Notification my stop-watch stops, and resets to 0.
Here is the Intent of the Notification:

```
            Intent msgIntent = new Intent(this, myActivity.class);
            msgIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(myActivity.this,
                    0, msgIntent,
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: android:launchMode = "singleTop" in Activity Manifest shoudl have solved the problem.

Comment: android:launchMode = "singleTop" solved my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If adding Flag didn't work as expected, easiest way to achieve your need is to define the particular Activity's launchMode inside manifest file. Eg:

```
<activity
        android:name=".myActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following dummy:

```
        Intent msgIntent = new Intent(this, myActivity.class);
        msgIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        msgIntent.putExtas(STOP, true);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(myActivity.this,
                0, msgIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

       //In your activity:
       onCreate() {
           if( getIntent().getBoolean(STOP) ) 
               then stop
       }

       onNewIntent(Intent _intent) {
          if( _intent.getBoolean(STOP) ) 
               then stop
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this method ,and problem is resoled,hope this can help you too;

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

intent.setClass(this, Main.class);

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
```